# Class SNMP Not Found on CentOS 6

Tags: php, snmp

Maybe I'm running low on coffee, maybe it's just because it's Monday, but for the life of me I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong. I've installed php-snmp.x86_64 5.3.3-47.el6 via yum, updated php.x86_64 to 5.3.3-47.el6 as yum required and restarted apache, but I'm still unable to create a new SNMP object like so (assume variables are instantiated beforehand):

```
$snmp = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $ip, $community, $snmp_timeout);
```

Error log states "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SNMP' not found". People on various forums are saying it's only available in PHP 5.4, but if that were the case why was I able to install it? The PHP SNMP installation page states "SNMP support has been restored in PHP 5.3.3."

I'm hoping that this is just one of those stupid mistakes that can be fixed with a missing include, but what am I missing here?

PHPInfo (from apache, not CLI) notes the following regarding SNMP:

```
Configure Command: --enable-ucd-snmp-hack
Additional .ini files parsed:  /etc/php.d/snmp.ini
NET-SNMP Support enabled
NET-SNMP Version 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing that module allows you to use the [SNMP functions](http://php.net/snmp) in PHP. Most of them have been around forever (like, the PHP 4.0 days) and certainly don't require SNMP 5.4. They are just basic wrappers around the C API functions and don't provide any object-oriented access to SNMP.

The [SNMP class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.snmp.php), on the other hand, *is* a new feature of PHP 5.4, so will not be available on such an old version.

I'd recommend using Remi's repository to upgrade to a modern PHP version. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/456968/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-latest-php-version-in-centos-with-yum/461418#461418) for details, though URLs may have changed.